# OpenCV 3.0 Why does number of keypoints go over threshold?

Tags: python, opencv

I created SIFT constructor, with Threshold = 20

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create(20)
keypoints, descriptors = sift.detectAndCompute(image,None)
```

Then I extract descriptors from sequence of images and for some images I receive number of keypoints bigger than limit by one. Please see descriptors print below:

```
(20, 128)
(20, 128)
(20, 128)
(20, 128)
(21, 128)
```

Is it a bug? How can I avoid this behavior?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d3c/classcv_1_1xfeatures2d_1_1SIFT.html#gsc.tab=0) says  *The number of best features to retain. The features are ranked by their scores (measured in SIFT algorithm as the local contrast)*

Which means that if you have 99 features and few after(3 for instance) have the same score, algorithm will return 102 features.

The logic is:

- we have 99 keypoints
- the next best keypoint set contains
- for example 4 keypoints so which one of the 4 keypoints we should add? The first one that comes in the image ?

Thanks to [Eduardo](http://answers.opencv.org/users/16447/eduardo/) for clearifying that logic.